Navigate a system menu programmatically with an android app
I have a very specific use case that causes me enough pain to write an app to do it.
I need the app to pass a short code to the dialer and navigate a menu with 2 steps.  I need to input a pin into the menu and then click ok.
I have tried using BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE and instrumentation but I can't get either to work since its not a system app.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />

This app is just for me, so I will be side loading it so I can do whatever I need to that doesn't require root.
I have been told this should be doable in Tasker, but I am not familiar enough with Tasker to create the automation, and there is some data manipulation I am doing along with it that is easier to do in Kotlin.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this, or is there a way to pass this task to Tasker to do?
